# join two seperate lines into one

Tags: python

I have a string that was created with(EDIT: This line of code cannot be modified):

`return "{}\r\n{}".format(" ".join("Hi are today"), " ".join("how you"))`

The string looks like this:

```
H i   a r e   t o d a y
h o w   y o u
```

How can I make it look like this?

```
Hi are today how you
```

I don't need the words in the right order, just the two lines on one

Comment: Use the `.replace()` function to replace the `\r\n` string with a space.

Comment: I've edited the real output. But what do you want as a result besides no line break? Do you want to remove those additional spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. As shammad said. Just remove, or replace the \r\n with spaces.

```
t = "{}\r\n{}".format(" ".join("Hi are today"), " ".join("how you"))
   
print(t.replace('\r\n','   '))

>> H i   a r e   t o d a y   h o w   y o u
```

Answer (score 1):

you already have the strings, by using `" ".join` on them you're getting a space between every character in them, why not just add the strings together with a space between:

```
>>> "Hi are today" + " " + "how you"
'Hi are today how you'
```

Or just join the 2 strings themselves together:

```
>>> ' '.join(("Hi are today", "how you"))
'Hi are today how you'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use join here? `str.join` is used to combine strings with specific delemter.

take a look at `\r\n`, its new line, you just need to remove this, you can do it as:

```py
return "{} {}".format("Hi are today","how you")
```

or like this with `join`

```py
return " ".join(["Hi are today","how you"])
```

if you want to just change the string you can do it as this:

```py
"{}\r\n{}".format(" ".join("Hi are today"), " ".join("how you")).replace("\r\n", " ")
```

`str.replace` is used to replace sequance of cahracters in string, you can read about it here: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)

Comment: The return statement I posted is not what I am concerned with. I cannot modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `\n`

`\n` is used to write in the next line.